# Why does tracemalloc print memory usage that is smaller than the file size?

Tags: python, file, io

Below is my code

```py
async def test():
    async with  aiofiles.open('somefile.json',"r") as f:
        line = await f.readline()  
        row = literal_eval(line)  
        return row
tracemalloc.start()
asyncio.run(test())
snapshot = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
top_stats = snapshot.statistics('lineno')
total = sum(stat.size for stat in top_stats)
print("Total allocated size: %.1f KiB" % (total / 1024))
```

`Somefile.json`is 10.6 mb. However, the total size of the output memory is `Total allocated size: 125.4 KiB`. Why is it smaller than the actual file size?

My file is 1 line json. `["k":{{"some_key": {"key2": ...}, "key1_1": {...},...}, "other_key": [{...}]]` This is how it's configured.

Comment: you read the file line per line....

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I could've confused you. My file is 1 line json. [{key:value}, {key:value},...] This is how it's configured.

Comment: Any particular reason you're discarding the loaded data?

Comment: And why are you using `ast.literal_eval` to load JSON? `ast.literal_eval` is for interpreting a restricted subset of Python syntax. `json.loads` is for loading JSON.

Comment: Something.json is not in the correct Jason format. To be exact, the file is a shambles of [{"some_key": {"key2": ...}, "key1_1": {...}...}, "other_key": [{...}]. To load and handle files, I used ast.literal_eval because it was easy to use